# resting password in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

so I had a problem in the rest password page, once you enter the email and click on send, the user get the email correctly, but when the user go the the rest password page and enter all the information, the password wouldn't rest correctly.

- Check the solution post.

Thank you

*** update:

full controller code:

```
<?php
use Care\Forms\ReminderForm;
class RemindersController extends Controller
{
    protected $reminderForm;
    function __construct(ReminderForm $reminderForm)
    {
        $this->reminderForm = $reminderForm;
    }
    public function getRemind()
    {
        return View::make('pages.remind');
    }
public function postRemind()
{
    $this->reminderForm->validate(Input::only('email'));
    $response = Password::remind(Input::only('email'), function($message)
    {
        $message->subject('Rest password');
    });
    switch ($response) {
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));
        case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
            return Redirect::back()->with('status', Lang::get($response));
    }
}
    public function getReset($token = null)
    {
        if (is_null($token)) App::abort(404);

        return View::make('pages.reset')->with('token', $token);
    }
    public function postReset()
    {
        $credentials = Input::only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
        $response = Password::reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
            $user->password = $password;
            $user->save();
        });
        switch ($response) {
            case Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
            case Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));
            case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So after some dinging here is the solution:

in the RemindersController.php change this line:
from:

```
$user->password = Hash::make($password);
```

to:

```
    $user->password = $password;
```

This is should solve your problem.

Comment: This is a bad idea. The reason Hash::make($password); is to store password in encrypted and salted format so if someone have access to your database, user accounts will be safe. By removing Hash, you are storing password as it is. Instead you need to check your controller where you compare password with $user->password like if `(Hash::make(Input::get('password'))===$user->password)`

Comment: @serdar.sanri actually what you wrote it does make sens, but how can I fix the problem? I'll update my post with the full controller code.

Comment: So when you said, it is not resetting correctly after you enter all details, what do you mean? what it not correct exactly? after you reset password, it doesn't accept new password when you try to login? or you can't see the password as you set in database?

Comment: @serdar.sanri after resting password, I can't login using the new password, it says wrong password. from what I've understand that when you type the new password it does not store correctly in the database.

Comment: ok, one more thing in order to user Password::reset your user model should be implementing UserInterface and RemindableInterface. Can you post your User model too. If you did so then the only thing I can see different than what I usually do is $credentials variable. When you send an reminder email it creates a token with the email link. All you need to do at that point is validate that token and let user enter password and password confirmation. Email is not necessary since that token is only valid for that user.